# Loop webpages with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a webpage that loops through a number of webpages much like the script in this post [Cycle scaled webpages in iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960102/cycle-scaled-webpages-in-iframe)

However it needs to be done without using iframes - any suggestions?

Comment: if you own all the pages you can add a script to go to the next website, although i find what i am saying really stupid

Answer (score 0):

In each page have

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30;url=http://yoursite.com/pagex.html">`

where 30 is seconds and the x is the page number of the NEXT page

Comment: unfortunately i don't have access to all the webpages I need to rotate through :(

Comment: then you are out of luck if you cannot use iFrame. And why can't you use iframe or frames?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming:

- These are all different websites, on different domains, so ajax isn't even possible (cross-site scripting issue)
- No control/access to editing the pages on these websites

Therefore to put it simply, **it's not possible** to cycle through pages without an iframe/or any frames under these circumstances.